# Cannot git push to Github

Tags: github, git-push, github-for-mac

I created a new Github repo on Github website and git cloned it on my local machine.
After making some changes in my local, I committed the changes and tried to push it the remote repo, but it fails with this message:

```
Learn.NET git:(master) git push
ERROR: Permission to GITHUB_ACCOUNT1/Learn.NET.git denied to GITHUB_ACCOUNT2.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Context:
I have two Github accounts, I created this repo on GITHUB_ACCOUNT1, but somehow it's trying to use my GITHUB_ACCOUNT2 account credentials to push, how can I make myself git pushable in this directory?

I've ssh configured on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out myself.

This command did the magic:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/GITHUB_ACCOUNT1/Learn.NET.git
```

After this, I was able to git push to the remote.